# Can jqgrid tree grid show user-defined icon

Tags: jqgrid, treegrid

This first picture is result by using jqGrid tree grid. The icon is default set, non Leaf item is start with "Inverted triangle", Leaf item is start with "o".

[image]

How can I set to make the display result like the second picture,I can set different icon for each row?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input data of the TreeGrid can contain `icon` property with the class name, which specify the icon of the tree leaf. The value of node properties should contain *two* classes: one for expanded node and one more for collapsed node. For example

```js
[
    { ...
        level: "0", parent: "null", isLeaf: false, expanded: true, loaded: true,
        icon: "ui-icon-folder-open,ui-icon-folder-collapsed" },
    { ...
        level: "1", parent: "1", isLeaf: true, expanded: false, loaded: true,
        icon: "ui-icon-flag" },
    { ...
        level: "2", parent: "2", isLeaf: true, expanded: false, loaded: true,
        icon: "ui-icon-star" },
    ...
]
```

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4svafpub/3/ demonstrates the TreeGrid, which displays

[image]

You don't posted any details what you do. No version of jqGrid, which you use, no information about the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). It's unknown which CSS framework you use: jQuery UI or Bootstrap and which icon set (jQuery UI icons,  Font Awesome 4.x, glyph icons of Bootstrap ...). The exact implementation of your requirements will depends on the information. In any way you will have to choose the icons classes from the set of icons, which you use or you will need to define custom CSS classes, which you will use for TreeGrid nodes and leafs, and to define CSS rules, which specify all required CSS properties: `background-image`, `background-position` and so on. As the result you will be able to display any icon which you need.

**UPDATED:** It seems to me that `icon` will be used only for leafs, not for nodes as it is described above.

**UPDATED 2:** I made some changes in the code of free jqGrid and now one can specify the icons for the nodes of TreeGrid. The same code with updated version of free jqGrid displays
[image]

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4svafpub/4/

Comment: I use free jqGrid, and the version is 4.5.2. I plan use jQuery UI icons. And I have try following your demo. I think this can meet current requirement. Thank you very much~

Comment: @Lisa: You are welcome! "free jqGrid" is the name on the product. "jqGrid" exist only till the version 4.7. After that Tony Tomov changed the name of the product, which he developed to "Guriddo jqGrid JS" (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)), changed the license agreement and made the product commercial (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). After that I started to develop the fork of jqGrid under the name ["free jqGrid"](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Thus you use currently retro version (4 years old) of the product, which not exist and not supported.

Comment: @Lisa: I recommend you to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.14.1 which have many new features, bug fixes and performance improvements. It's compatible to jqGrid 4.5.2. You can load free jqGrid files directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). I recommend you to read [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) additionally.

Comment: @Lisa: See **UPDATED 2** part of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your  expatiation and demo. I will try change free jqGrid 4.14.1. Really thanks! BTW, could you help me look into this question about make multi-checkbox in one tree grid cell?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281427/add-multi-checkbox-in-one-tree-grid-cell