# I need to update the icons in a jqgrid tree dynamically when the cell is rendered

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to render a jqgrid tree but he icons associated with the leaf I want to override the default values with values provided in the data. Let's say that one of the data columns is:
{name: "icon",width:1,hidden:true},
and has values such "ui-icon-alert", "ui-icon-bullet", "ui-icon-radio-off"

Is there any call back function to do this? if so how would you call it?

--UPDATE
Actually I think I found a possible answer here:[TreeGrid](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/)

When I look at the data being supplied

```
{
"rows":[
    {"category_id":"1","name":"ELECTRONICS","price":"0.00","qty_onhand":"0","color":"","lft":"1","rgt":"44","level":"0","uiicon":""},
    {"category_id":"2","name":"TELEVISIONS","price":"0.00","qty_onhand":"0","color":"","lft":"2","rgt":"19","level":"1","uiicon":""},
    {"category_id":"3","name":"TUBE","price":"0.00","qty_onhand":"0","color":"","lft":"3","rgt":"8","level":"2","uiicon":""},
]
}
```

I am not sure if this would work. But I also don't know what values lft and rgt are supposed to have. I know level determines the parent/child relationship.
Does anybody knows which is the best way?

Comment: Look at [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4svafpub/11/) created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44278952/315935) and [the oldest one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9482049/315935) about the subject. It shows how to overwrite default icons for some specific leafs or nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see that you find a solution in our [Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net).
Actually you can get more information in our [new released documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/treegrid/)